# How to open a PDF file in SSRS that is stored as binary data in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm working on an invoice report and what I need to do is when user clicks on a specific invoice, then I like to show the PDF file.

The only thing that I came close to the solution was here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34551/Reporting-Services-2008-Embedding-a-PDF-Document.

The article is 6 years old and I was wondering if anyone can help with a little bit of less complicated solution.

Thanks in advance!

JA

Comment: Can't you just have the PDF files in a network folder and reference them with a text box Go To URL **ACTION**?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That is an option but I was wondering if there are any other options.

Comment: The PDF Embedding looks a lot more trouble that it's worth. I don't see what the benefit is other than you don't need a PDF reader. I can't think of any other way to do it.